# SOAP PHP date time issue

Tags: php, date, soap, format

When passing array in SOAP request like this, its working fine

```
$parameters = array(date'=>'2016-08-27T00:00:00','aa'=>'aaaa');
```

But when i store the date value in a php variable and pass its showing error

```
$date = '2016-08-27T00:00:00';
$parameters = array(date'=>'$date','aa'=>'aaaa');
```

Fault code: soap:Client
Fault string: Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 592). ---> The string '$date' is not a valid AllXsd value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $date value will be passed litterally as '$date' instead of '2016-08-27T00:00:00'. Use double quotes instead (or no quotes at all):

```
$parameters = array('date'=>"$date",'aa'=>'aaaa');
```